# Closing and Reopening Android App

Tags: android

I'm making an Android app with two activities, a main menu and a game activity. So far the app runs fine, and switching back and forth between activities works as it should. A problem arises though when the game activity is running and I press the home button. When I tap the icon to reopen the game, it opens to a black screen and doesn't do anything. I created all of the life cycle methods and print messages each time one is called, but when I try to reopen the app, it doesn't call onCreate(), onStart(), or onResume() for either of the two activities. If I go to task manager and close the app, then go to reopen it, it opens up to the main menu activity as expected. The problem only arises when I hit the home button and then try to open the app again. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is some code from my game activity, including all the life cycle methods:

```
public class Klondike extends Activity{

private KlondikeGameView gameView;
private StatsHandler statsHandler;
private KlondikeGameStats gameStats;
private RelativeLayout mainLayout;
public boolean createSavedGame;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    createSavedGame = true;
    setContentView(R.layout.klondike);
    mainLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_klondike_layout);
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    this.statsHandler = new StatsHandler();
    this.gameStats = new KlondikeGameStats(System.currentTimeMillis());

    gameView = new KlondikeGameView(getApplicationContext(), this, dm.heightPixels, dm.widthPixels, statsHandler, gameStats);
    mainLayout.addView(gameView);
    gameView.startGameThread();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    System.out.println("OnStart was called for Klondike");
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println("OnResume was called for Klondike");
    if (KlondikeSaveHandler.checkIfSavedStateExists(getApplicationContext())){
        KlondikeSaveHandler.restoreSavedState(getApplicationContext(), gameStats, gameView.getGameBoard());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    System.out.println("OnPause was called for Klondike");
    if (createSavedGame){
        KlondikeSaveHandler.prepareSavedGame(getApplicationContext(), gameStats, gameView.getGameBoard());
        System.out.println("Game saved");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Game not eligible for saving");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    System.out.println("OnStop was called for Klondike");
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    System.out.println("OnRestart was called for Klondike");
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    System.out.println("OnDestroy was called for Klondike");
}
}
```

After I hit the home button, onPause is called, and the game is saved correctly.

Here is the manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.thomas.solitaire" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.thomas.solitaire.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.app.thomas.solitaire.Klondike"
            android:label="Klondike"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you checked to see what lifecycle methods get called when you hit the homebutton - ie onPause, onStop and possibly onDestroy? If you find out what state the activity is put into once you have pressed the home button, it could give you some insight into why those lifecycle methods are possibly not getting called. Also, some code from your game activity to give the general flow of the activity would be helpful.

Comment: Yes I have, when I hit the home button, just onPause is called

Comment: Can you post your manifest file?

Comment: In every activity that is being shown, when you hit the home button, onPause() will be invoked, and when you resume the app again, onResume() will be called, that's the nature of an android app lifecycle, if you are encountring a black screen, you may be missing in your custom view "KlondikeGameView".

Comment: Ok, I posted it the manifest file. @Arman I tried creating the KlondikeGameView in onResume() but it yielded the same result, just a black screen. However, when I resume the app, it isn't printing that onResume() was even called. onPause() is called when I press the home button, but onResume() is never called when I open it again. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

try putting

```
gameView = new KlondikeGameView(getApplicationContext(), this, dm.heightPixels, dm.widthPixels, statsHandler, gameStats);
mainLayout.addView(gameView);
gameView.startGameThread();
```

in onResume() than in onCreate()

Comment: I moved that to the onResume() method but it's still the same result, just a black screen.

Comment: There is no possible way your onResume() method doesn't get called. Come on think logically(you might be facing a problem, I'm sure). Try commenting out the code in all methods accept onCreate() and Log statements in these methods. If it still doesnt work comment the onCreate() except setcontentView. I know this sounds silly, but its very effective, as soon as you start getting these log statements you will have whats wrong with the code.